# Please capitalize "muslims" in the description of Islam.SE on StackExchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spelling, capitalization

I noticed a small typo here:

https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic

> Q&A for muslims, experts in Islam, and those interested in learning
> more about Islam

Please capitalize "muslims" to "Muslims", since this is a proper noun.

Comment: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Obligatory comment about [being bludgeoned to death with a giant... er, capital M](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

Comment: @SamIam If it were capitalized incorrectly on the Islam site itself I'd migrate this.  However, since it's wrong on the main Stack Exchange site (and this is the de facto Meta for the whole network, at least for the time being), I think this is the right place to ask.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Technically the site's [FAQ description](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq) is wrong, and fixing that would fix the site list I think, but this wouldn't exactly be the first time a per-site problem was posted here

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Yeah, it looks like you're right about that. Now I wonder where it's more effective to have this question posted (in terms of getting a change done sooner). I'll keep an eye on it and bounce it over to the Islam Meta if it doesn't get fixed soon.